# Given two numpy arrays, how to split one into an array of lists based on the second

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance

I have two numpy arrays: one containing arbitrary values, and one containing integers larger than 1. The sum of the integers is equal to the length of the first array. Sample:

```py
values = np.array(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"])
lengths = np.array([1, 3, 2, 2])
len(values) == sum(lengths) # True
```

I would like to split the first array according to the lengths of the second array, and end up with something like:

```py
output = np.array([["a"], ["b", "c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g", "h"]], dtype=object)
```

It's easy to iterate over the array with a Python loop, but it's also slow when both lists are very large (hundreds of millions of elements). Is there a way to do this operation using native numpy operations, which presumably should be must faster?

Comment: The 'native' `split` and `split_array` also have to loop, taking multiple slices.  And they produce a list of arrays, which is a bit different from your object dtype array of lists.  This isn't a 'native' operation like `reshape`.

Comment: Yes, @hpaulj: the following solution appears to be much faster: `cl = np.cumsum(lengths)

[values[x[0]:x[1]] for x in zip([0] + cl[:-1].tolist(), cl)]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `split` method from numpy:

```
output = np.split(values, np.cumsum(lengths))[:-1]
```

Comment: Ah, using split with cumsum is obvious in retrospect. Thanks!